# Is there any way to control the sorting of elements when using jquery ui

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, sorting, draggable

I have a sortable div (`#sortable`) with elements (`.draggable`) inside it. In there, when I sort elements from bottom to up, the elements can easily be sorted by dragging up and I don't have to drag much to the top. But when sorting elements from up to bottom, I have to drag the element far below then wanted. Is there any way to control the sorting of elements, so that even if I drag just a little bit up/below and not all the way up/down it will display the placeholder to place the element respectively?

Demo at [codepen](http://codepen.io/aamus/pen/qOrpEZ?editors=001).

js

```
  $('#content #sortable').sortable({
    handle: '.drag_handle',
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    axis: "y"
  });

  $('#blocks .draggable').draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    revert: "invalid",
    connectToSortable: '#content #sortable'
  });
```

**update**

Sorting upwards

Sorting upwards is easy as I don't have to drag the element all the way up above the element I want to sort with.

[image]

Sorting downwards

Sorting downwards is difficult as I have to drag the element all the way down below the element I want to sort with.

[image]

Comment: I’m having trouble understanding the question. Could you provide a sketch or some additional explanation?

Comment: @polarblau Please check this [codepen](http://codepen.io/aamus/pen/qOrpEZ?editors=100) demo. When I drag/sort the element up then I don't have to drag all the way to the end of the up element, but when I drag down I have to drag all the way down below the element. What I want is when I drag/sort element say 5px below then leave a placeholder for that element, so that I don't have to drag all the way down element below.

Comment: Alright, I think I gotcha. Thanks!

Comment: @polarblau Can you help me with it?

Comment: Not of the top of my head but I’ll try to take a closer look. I’m sure it would help to get more views if you try to add some visuals. It took me quite a while to follow what you were after.

Comment: @polarblau Ok. And I have updated with some visuals to understand better. :)

Comment: Hmm. When I sort in Firefox, the upper placeholder appears after I leave the middle of the element to the top. The lower placeholder appears, after I leave the middle of the element to the bottom. Looks pretty normal or don't I understand your problem?

Comment: @VolkerAndres Maybe just in the chrome then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just change the `tolerance` option of the [sortable API](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#option-tolerance) to `"pointer"`. This option will make the draggable considered to be on the placeholder when the cursor is over it (what you need right now) instead of wait until over 50% of the element is overlapping the placeholder. This was why you had to scroll way too far down in order to sort it.

```
$('#content #sortable').sortable({
    handle: '.drag_handle',
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    tolerance: "pointer"
});
```

Here is the updated [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epWmMm?editors=001)

Comment: Thank you. This was killing me.

Comment: The bounty can be awarded after 7 hrs, will do after that. Thanks again.